# Jupyter extension no longer working with python in VScode

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

I have a Mac running High Sierra 10.13.6. I've been learning Python using VScode. In VScode, I installed several extensions including the Jupyter extension. As per directions for the Jupyter extension I added #%% as the first line of my python script files. When I did that the words "Run cell" would appear right above the #%% line in my script file. I would click on "run cell" and my script would execute in the same window as my file. Very nice!

That doesn't work anymore. I had problems with VScode which I thought I had solved. My script still runs in VScode using Code Runner but the #%% seems to no longer have any effect. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: "Doesn't work anymore" as in you click it and nothing happens? Or the "run cell" code lens is now gone? If it's the former I would check the Output window to see if there's something there for the Jupyter extension. If it's the latter then the extension changed.

Comment: the 'Run Cell' code lens no longer appears. I tried reloading the Jupyter extension but no luck.

Comment: Then I would file a bug on the extension.